# In Adobe AEM how to retrieve non-Content-Fragment nodes via GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, aem, sling, aem-6

I have set up content fragment models and some instances that I am able to retrieve via GraphQL in AEM (Cloud Service). Now, for each content fragment I would like to have a subfolder with the very same name and a certain suffix ("_images") containing images. So, for instance this is a CF

```
/content/dam/myproject/mycf
```

And these are images belonging to that particular CF

```
/content/dam/myproject/mycf_images/image1.jpg
/content/dam/myproject/mycf_images/video.jpg
```

Is there are chance to retrieve them via GraphQL?

I could create content references in my CF but first, this is extra effort to link each of them instead of having a convention, second, there is no dynamic list in the CF model editor for content references.

Other idea would be to directly export the node via the .json selector but then I would obtain all the nodes properties instead of only the business information.